# Xcode: Build for archiving success but no app-file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build, provisioning

I am very desperate at the moment. I developed an iPhone application and when I am "building for archiving" I get the message "Build succeded" but actually no app-file is created.

My guess is that it has sthg to do with the provisioning but I checked all profiles, I even deleted all profiles and my certificate and reinstalled them but nothing changes.

When I am using building for testing it does create the app though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the scheme you are using and check that a target is ticked for Archive in the Build section.

Comment: It worked - I just uploaded my app to iTunes! Thanks for helping me out so quickly!

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the just a Achieve under Project menu. If you cannot see that Achieve menu is not active, then you have configure your distribution profile.